# How can I update the point clouds in the slam problem?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At present, many methods have been proposed to solve the slam problem,such as rgbdslam ,I meet a problem,When robot visted a place which is visted before, There is a new  obstacle ,generallly，The researchers  increase the point clouds of obstacle on the original slam.who have done some jobs to update  the point clouds?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199450/how-can-i-update-the-point-clouds-in-the-slam-problem?/) by [yincanben](https://answers.ros.org/users/20734/yincanben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a point cloud representation of the map, the points are usually added.

In a 2D or 3D occupancy grid, the grid cells are usually updated probabilistically depending on how many times the sensor looked at *something in the cell* and how many times it *looked through the cell*.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0